# Osmium and OSM: Remove a relation from .pbf map file

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, open-source-routing-machine, osmium, denmark

I am trying to use `osmium` to remove a relation from a .pbf file (specifically the Denmark extract from Geofabrik)1. The relation is part of a cycle network. I essentially want to calculate routing distance without this relation using `osrm`.

I've tried to use `--omit-referenced` to remove the relation and create a new file, but this doesn't seem to be correct and my output still contains the relation when I check it by converting the `.pbf` to `.opl`. An example of the code I am using is below.

Is someone able to advise what I am doing wrong, or is there a better way to remove the specific relation?

```
osmium tags-filter -i denmark-latest.osm.pbf wr/id=12295434 --omit-referenced -o 2021_4.osm.pbf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with osmium but the ID is not a tag! I suppose that's why `tags-filter` and `wr/id=12295434` won't do what you are looking for.

Try [`removeid`](https://docs.osmcode.org/osmium/latest/osmium-removeid.html) instead:

```
osmium removeid denmark-latest.osm.pbf r12295434 -o 2021_4.osm.pbf
```

Comment: thank you so much! this did the trick.